# Cells number format breaks in one column only if multiple cells are moved

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, microsoft-excel-365

I have a table where I keep track of best times & corresponding dates in pairs of cells. Time on top with the date below it, stored in range [B3:E10]. The time values are entered into the formula area as "12:08:31" (hh:mm:ss) and the number formatting for the time cells is set to [mm:ss] to only show the minutes and seconds in the cell as "8:31".
The dates are entered as text.

[Time values shown start at [B7] in yellow and their date values start at [B8] below, and continue right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUREh.png)

**Problem**: The time cells in column C lose formatting when I move multiple time values (of the same row) at once, left or right, across column C. With or without dates also selected & moved. This does not happen if it's only 1 time value moved into column C.

[Table showing the C column's broken formatting [C7:C8]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj9Ar.png)

For example: If I select the cells of [B7:D8] (time row:date row) and click & drag to move it right one column to [C7:E8] the time cell of my C column loses the number formatting. (This happens with any "time" row; 3,5,7,9). The time value in the formula area inserts a "1/0/1900" before the original time value, so the cell itself will show the time as "0-Jan-00". This only happens with the C column, I can't replicate the issue for any other range.

What's really confusing me is that the [mm:ss] formatting for column C's time values don't break if only 1 time value is moved into the C column (of any row).

[With the 2 columns of data on the right already moved, I moved [B7:B8] to [C7:C8] and it doesn't break.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYV13.png)

Why is it just my C column? From what I can tell, the formatting for other columns time cells aren't set any differently, but something's wrong.